# Nunit GUI interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit

I have succesfully made a test class that imports using `using NUnit.Framework;`

To the left i have a icon to run the test so far so good.

But how exactly do i use the external graphical interface of NUnit?
If i try to create a new project it ask for a name, but when i click save nothing happends.

How exactly can i link my project to this GUI?

In options i enabled Visual Studio support. Also i made a new project in the interface and tried to add VS project but i am running a ASP website, so i do not have a .proj file exentsion for that.

What should i use for TTD when making a Asp website application? MS Test has proven horrible and was unable to get that to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "To the left i have a icon" To the left of what?

Answer (score 3):

My usual way of using the gui is to create a test class in C# in visual studio. Then open the DLL that is created when you compile the assembly. It will show your tests and you can run them